# VSCode - Rubocop - Settings.json - End of file expected

Tags: json, ruby, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I am using VisualStudioCode with Ruby and Rubocop. After installation of Rubocop i found out i must change some of the settings in settings.json for Rubocop.
How do i fix this error => End of file expected (5,1).

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"
}

{
"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "C:\\Games\\Ruby24-x64\\bin\\",
"ruby.rubocop.onSave": true
}
```

VSCode says: End of file expected (5,1). But to me it seems everything OK.

Comment: Does the code execute without syntax errors?

Comment: Yes, VSCode just says:  [jsonc] End of file expected. (5,1)

Comment: Just wondering, EOF errors never point to where the problem actually is, just to when the interpreter finally discovers its missing an `end` or a brace, etc. I personally do not know, never had that problem with the linter. It typically sees things that I do not when it comes to those types of problems.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Why would your rubocop path end with `ruby.exe\ `? Usually `\ ` in the end of a path means it is a directory - if it is a file (or executable) it should not end with a backslash. I don't know if that is related to your issue but you should remove that imo.

Comment: I have tried first without ruby.exe but then i added it and it doesnt work too. I will remove since i also know that it is unecessary (ruby.exe). But it doesnt work without it either.

Comment: I didn't address the `ruby.exe`, my problem is the (escaped) backslash after it. That just shouldn't be there. Did you try to completely leave this argument out, by setting `  "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "",` as recommended? Also, what does `rubocop --version` output and what does `where rubocop` (assuming you are on windows since you did link an .exe file) tell you?

Comment: If i delete 1 \ it doesnt work.

Comment: I did check the recommended tab and i did it right (ruby.rubocop.executePath).

Comment: Rubocop --version gets me 0.58.0. And where rubocop gets me "C:\Games\Ruby24-x64\bin\rubocop
C:\Games\Ruby24-x64\bin\rubocop.bat".

Comment: No matter if i put / or \\ it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know VSCode, but your settings file is not valid JSON because it has multiple root elements. Try combining them, i.e.:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
"ruby.rubocop.executePath": "C:\\Games\\Ruby24-x64\\bin\\",
"ruby.rubocop.onSave": true
}
```

You can validate the syntax using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/